# Perl6: why does substr-rw behave this way?

Tags: substr, raku

Why does here `substr-rw` cut off the trailing `6`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6;

my $str = '123';
$str ~= '.' x 30;
$str ~= '456';

say $str;       #   123..............................456
$str.substr-rw( 0, 10 ) = '';
say $str;       #   ........................45
```

---

```
perl6 --version
This is Rakudo version 2016.03-38-g8df1a69 built on MoarVM version 2016.03-46-g50c7f6a implementing Perl 6.c.
```

Comment: Confirmed with Rakudo version 2016.01.1

Comment: [RT#127782](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=127782)

Comment: this bug has [just been fixed](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/commit/c01472d7c539a8eea55b8443dc99e494437b7fdc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:** *A Rakudo/MoarVM built after 2016-07-21 should behave correctly.*

Looks like a bug to me. Note that it matters how the string is constructed:

```
my $a = '.' x 3 ~ 'x';
my $b = sprintf('%s', $a); # or just '...x', but not "$a"

say $a; #=> ..x
say $b; #=> ..x

$a.substr-rw( 0, 2 ) = '';
$b.substr-rw( 0, 2 ) = '';

say $a; #=> ..
say $b; #=> .x
```

Update: The bug has been reported: [RT#127782](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=127782)